# Overloading hidden summary.lm methods in R

Tags: r, methods, built-in, overloading

In R, `summary.lm` is "hidden" (marked by asterisk when I look at `methods('summary'))`.

I defined a `pvalue` object and `as.pvalue` function so that when the pvalue is very small, the `print.pvalue` method prints as a character, e.g. "<0.001" rather than the floating point number with ridiculously impractical precision.

I want to overload `summary.lm` to make the `Pr(>|t|)` column a pvalue object instead of a double. I could copy the source code. Another approach I thought to try was:

```
summary.lm <- function (object, correlation = FALSE, symbolic.cor = FALSE, 
    ...) {
  ans <- base::summary.lm(object, correlation = FALSE, symbolic.cor = FALSE, 
    ...)
  ans$coefficients$`Pr(>|t|)` <- as.pvalue(ans$coefficients$`Pr(>|t|)`)
  ans
}
```

but `base::summary.lm` isn't callable. I changed it to `base::summary` and crashed R with a recursive loop that R didn't know how to stop. (Anything called "foolproof" underestimates the power of fools).

Is it possible to write such a function in this way?

Comment: `printCoefmat` has an `eps.Pvalue` argument. Is there any way to make use of it?

Comment: @BenBolker great suggestion. Also has a way to turn the stupid stars off.

Answer (score 0):

Oh shoot, the namespace for `summary.lm` is `stats::` and not `base::`.